# Update PHP version on Windows 10 not using XAMPP etc

Tags: php, installation

I currently have PHP installed on Windows 10 via AMPPS which seems to have stopped being updated. The latest version of PHP available from the AMPPS GUI is 7.1.

I want the latest version of PHP, but it is very hard to find out how to get it. I have found this page: https://windows.php.net/download/ but there doesn't seem to an any installer or suchlike, and I have no idea which option to download or what to do once I've downloaded it.

Isn't there some simple way to do this? I have composer installed if that helps.

Maybe something like `composer upadte-php` from `powershell` or something equally simple and user-friendly? Or maybe `php --update`.

If not, could someone please explain the process in simple steps. I certainly need the new version in my system path too.

Comment: Did you try search for _"install php 7.4 on windows"_ on google/bing? If you do, you'll find many many guides. Even if some guide are using some earlier version of PHP, the method should still be the same.

Comment: Yes I did, but no results were clear or relevant enough for my needs.

Comment: Here's a guide that's very clear: http://kizu514.com/blog/install-php7-and-composer-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson those few words "Download the latest PHP7 (non-thread safe version) zip file from http://windows.php.net/" made all the difference. I'm not sure how a newbie could ever know that from the info on the downloads page - maybe a little hint like "use this one if you don't know what you are doing" would be helpful!

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft never succeeds in implementing a usable and secure software management as it is present in other operating systems. Where you can simply select whatever you want to install or upgrade with a single moue click _without_ having to search through the internet and downloading artefacts you have no way to check for validity.